# Make all words uppercase in Wordcloud in R

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, word-cloud

When creating Wordclouds it is most common to make all the words lowercase. However, I want the wordclouds to display the words uppercase. After forcing the words to be uppercase the wordcloud still display lowercase words. Any ideas why?

Reproducable code:

```
    library(tm)
    library(wordcloud)

data <- data.frame(text = c("Creativity is the art of being ‘productive’ by using
          the available resources in a skillful manner. 
          Scientifically speaking, creativity is part of
          our consciousness and we can be creative –
          if we know – ’what goes on in our mind during
          the process of creation’.
          Let us now look at 6 examples of creativity which blows the mind."))

text <- paste(data$text, collapse = " ")

# I am using toupper() to force the words to become uppercase.
text <- toupper(text)

source <- VectorSource(text)
corpus <- VCorpus(source, list(language = "en"))

# This is my function for cleaning the text                  
clean_corpus <- function(corpus){
             corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
             corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
             corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
             corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c(stopwords("en")))
             return(corpus)
}   

clean_corp <- clean_corpus(corpus)
data_tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(clean_corp)
data_m <- as.matrix(data_tdm)

commonality.cloud(data_m, colors = c("#224768", "#ffc000"), max.words = 50)
```

This produces to following output

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because behind the scenes `TermDocumentMatrix(clean_corp)` is doing `TermDocumentMatrix(clean_corp, control = list(tolower = TRUE))`. If you set it to `TermDocumentMatrix(clean_corp, control = list(tolower = FALSE))`, then the words stay uppercase. Alternatively, you can also adjust the row names of your matrix afterwards: `rownames(data_m) <- toupper(rownames(data_m))`.

Comment: Thanks, am I right to think it makes more sense to upper the rownames after cleaning since the cleaning, in particular the removing of stopwords, assume lowercase?

Comment: That way, you'd convert to lower case and afterwards convert to uppercase. So I'd just specify the control argument.