# What's making the texts lowercase in this Corpora, and how can I turn it uppercase?

Tags: r, uppercase, corpus, word-cloud

I'm trying to build a word cloud in `R`, but it's returning only lowercase texts.

```
sheet <- read_excel('list_products.xls', skip = 4)
products <- c(sheet$Cod)
products <- Corpus(VectorSource(products))
c_words <- brewer.pal(8, 'Set2')
wordcloud(products, min.freq = 10, max.words = 30, scale = c(7,1), colors = c_words)
```

Once I've tried putting the following code before the wordcloud function, and it's not working:

```
products <- tm_map(products, content_transformer(toupper))
```

What's making the texts lowercase, and what should I do to turn it o uppercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you can see from here: [Make all words uppercase in Wordcloud in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653728/make-all-words-uppercase-in-wordcloud-in-r), when you do `TermDocumentMatrix(CORPUS)`, by default words get lowercase.
Indeed, if you do `trace(wordcloud)` when there is not argument `freq`,  `tdm <- tm::TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)` is executed, so you words go lowercase.

You have two options to solve this:
Include words and freq instead of corpus:

```
filePath <- "http://www.sthda.com/sthda/RDoc/example-files/martin-luther-king-i-have-a-dream-speech.txt" # I am using this text because you DID NOT PROVIDED A REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE
text <- readLines(filePath)
products <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
products <- tm_map(products, toupper)
c_words <- brewer.pal(8, 'Set2')
tdm <- tm::TermDocumentMatrix(products, control = list(tolower = F))
freq_corpus <- slam::row_sums(tdm)
wordcloud(names(freq_corpus), freq_corpus, min.freq = 10, max.words = 30, scale = c(7,1), colors = c_words)
```

And you will get:

[image]

The second option is to modify wordcloud:

First you do `trace(worcloud, edit=T)` and then substitute line 21 by:

`tdm <- tm::TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(tolower = F))`

Click save and execute:

```
filePath <- "http://www.sthda.com/sthda/RDoc/example-files/martin-luther-king-i-have-a-dream-speech.txt"
text <- readLines(filePath)
products <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
products <- tm_map(products, toupper)
c_words <- brewer.pal(8, 'Set2')
wordcloud(names(freq_corpus), freq_corpus, min.freq = 10, max.words = 30, scale = c(7,1), colors = c_words)
```

You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort to respond with such clear instructions. And I'm sorry for not providing enough content to reproduce my code.